# Can WCF services running in WcfSvcClient run under a domain account?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have a client where I'm trying to port their code to my machine for development purposes. They built their wcf services using classes and interfaces only - thus no svc files. Almost like you would find with self hosting.

When I run the application, these services are hosted by WcfSvcClient (for debugging purposes) and I can see them starting up. I can however not access these services by pointing my browser to the given urls, nor can I step into that code.

I know this should work, because it works on a client machine - but I cannot tell why it isn't working on my machine other than suspecting it needs a computer which runs on their domain?

The strange thing I've noticed is they declared a host url in the wcf services config file for each service. This url is used when starting WcfSvcClient - but it is not configured anywhere else I can see i.e. not IIS. It just mysteriously exists and I have no idea how to call it, debug it or even under which account it runs. Is this configurable somewhere?

Could someone perhaps point me in the right direction? My knowledge with wcf is very limited. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems wsHttpBinding does support authentication where the domain the service is running on is relevant. This is it's default behavior. You have to explicitly tell it to not do so, by including:

```
securityMode=None
```

in your binding configuration. **Not suggested for production**.

For more information see this post: [WCF slow ServiceHost.Open() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739546/wcf-slow-servicehost-open-cal)